# rails 3.1 upgrade from 3.0. Error in rendering.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I upgraded rails from 3.0.20 to 3.1.12. I have not yet enabled the asset pipeline. I am right now stuck at this error below. Getting it on every request. Any ideas?

```
Error during failsafe response: wrong number of arguments (6 for 5)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:85:in `find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:85:in `find_template'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `__send__'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:23:in `determine_template'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:106:in `with_fallbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `__send__'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `with_fallbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:23:in `determine_template'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:89:in `rescue_action_locally'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:69:in `render_exception'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application.rb:143:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@rails3112/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271115/rails-3-1-upgrade-error

Comment: Yes I did. I dont have that gem installed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about it is:

1. start a new rails 3.1.12 project and see if it runs.
2. add the gems to your Gemfile and see if everything still works.
3. start importing some of your files in this order:

   1. environment.rb and environment files such as development.rb
   2. files in config/initializers
   3. your config/routes.rb
   4. files under app/