# Rails - Everytime I create a new project I get: Error during failsafe response: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I create new projects in rails using *rails new project_name* and then start my server at localhost:3000, I keep getting the following error:

```
  Rendered /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (8.4ms)
Error during failsafe response: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in `parse_query'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/request.rb:191:in `GET'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in `GET'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb:59:in `formats'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb:22:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `render_exception'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:35:in `rescue in call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Banait/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
^C[2015-06-18 17:01:18] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2015-06-18 17:01:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

All existing projects start up just fine. Just new ones are effected. I didn't install any gem or any application prior to this error. Just happened out of no where. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271115/rails-3-1-upgrade-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to see if it works. Go to your Gemfile.lock and find `rack (1.6.3)` change it back to `rack (1.6.2)`. Bundler updated that. And then try again.